# $\text{Var}(y)$ in linear regression

Tags: regression, variance, linear-model, descriptive-statistics, linear

In linear regression, why is $\text{Var}(y)$ different?

$$\text{Var}(y) = \sigma^2$$

But somebody says it should be that. What?

$$\text{Var}(y) = \beta_1^2 \text{Var}(x) + \sigma^2$$

Comment: Hi: Even they don't do it in the textbooks,  it's better to think of it as VAR(y | x ) so that $x$ is fixed and therefore not a random variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $y_i \sim \mathcal N(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i,\sigma^2 )$, the variance of each sample $y_i$ is $\sigma^2$. This is a conditional variance, $\operatorname{Var}(y|x)$.

The sample variance of all samples $y$ is a marginal variance. It's given by the common formulas
$$\operatorname{Var}(y)
=\mathbb E\left[y^2\right]- E\left[y\right]^2
=\mathbb E\left[(y-\mathbb E\left[y\right])^2\right]
$$

If $y = \beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$, we can use variance identities and the fact that $\operatorname{Cov}(x,\epsilon)=0$ to show that:

$$\operatorname{Var}(y)=\operatorname{Var}(\beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon)\\
=\operatorname{Var}(\beta_1x)+\color{blue}{\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon)}+2\operatorname{Cov}(\beta_1x,\epsilon)\\
=\beta_1^2\operatorname{Var}(x)+\color{blue}{\sigma^2}+2\beta_1\color{red}{\operatorname{Cov}(x,\epsilon)}\\
=\beta_1^2\operatorname{Var}(x)+\sigma^2
$$

Thus, both are right, but they refer to different things.

Comment: Thanks! why first one is a normal distributed with mean = $\beta_1x_i$?

Comment: @kuku it was missing a $\beta_0$, now I corrected it, but the reason why is that's actually part of the model, we assume that

Comment: -1: This is not the answer to the question. The difference in the 2 expressions has to do with whether X is random or non-random. Your answer suggests that one answer is correct and the other one is not. That is not the case. They are both correct. I'll be happy to upvote your answer if you added the missing part that shows Var(y) when x is non-random.

Comment: Why does an *estimate* "$\hat\sigma^2$" appear as an expression for the *assumed* variance of $\epsilon$?  In effect, your formula relies on equating this estimate with $\sigma^2,$ which is incorrect.

Comment: @whuber it's the sample variance of $\epsilon$ though, and it's not equated with the intrinsic variance $\sigma^2$. I see your point though, I did not need to speak in terms of sample statistics to arrive at the conclusion. I got there because I wanted to introduce the relationship with $\text{RSS}$, but I can get there otherwise. I might edit this later. Anything else wrong that I can correct?

Comment: I think you are incorrect: by *definition,* $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $\epsilon.$  Thus $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon)=\sigma^2,$ not $\hat\sigma^2.$

Comment: @whuber Indeed, it's the population variance of $\epsilon$ but I'm talking in terms of samples, that's why I can state the relationship between $\hat \sigma^2$ and $\text{RSS}$. Do you take $\operatorname{Var}$ to only mean population variance? I can rearrange notation anyways

Comment: Whether you are "talking in terms of samples" or not does not change the mathematics!  In this post, $y$ is a random variable.  There are no rules of probability or statistics that permit you to replace its mathematical properties with estimated properties.

Comment: Please also do not forget to address the fact that the OP asked which of the 2 expressions is correct: $Var(y)=\sigma^2$ or $Var(y)=\beta_1^2Var(X)+\sigma^2$. You have not answered that question. If your answer is the second one, that is incorrect under the assumption that x is non-random. The correct answer is both are correct and that should be explained. When x is non-random the first is correct (or can be seen as a special case of the second). When X is random the second one is correct. This is the heart of the question; not the derivation of Var(y) when X is random.

Comment: To put it in different words: a student reading an Econometrics book (say Wooldridge) will see the second expression while a student reading a Statistics book (say Weisberg) will see the first expression. Is one of the authors wrong? Clearly not. But what explains this difference. That is the question and I am not sure you understand the difference.

Comment: +1: thanks for the edit